# Pandas Error when I compare two columns of 2 different csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv, difference

I wrote a function to compare 2 columns (with same names) in 2 differents dataframes, in case of my scraping stopped, I can begin again with only the urls not **scraped**.

```
def diff(list1, list2):
    return list(set(list1).symmetric_difference(set(list2)))


if os.path.isfile("dataset\\infos.csv"):
    # instructions
    tableauInfos = pd.read_csv('dataset\\infos.csv', encoding="utf-8", sep=',', names=colonnes, dtype="unicode")
    tableauLiens = pd.read_csv('dataset\\liensVilles.csv', encoding="utf-8", sep=',', dtype="unicode")
    colonnes1 = tableauInfos['lien']
    colonnes2 = tableauLiens['lien']
    listeLiens = diff(colonnes1, colonnes2)
else:
    # instructions
    tableauInfos = DataFrame(columns = colonnes)
    tableauInfos.to_csv('dataset\\infos.csv', index=False)
    tableauLiens = pd.read_csv('dataset\\liensVilles.csv', encoding="utf-8", sep=',', dtype="unicode")
    listeLiens = tableauLiens['lien']
```

I verify first if the file exists, if yes I retrieve the two columns and I apply the diff function. All is okay, but many times, during the **scrape**, the code stops with the following error:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str
```

And when in the end (when lot of urls are **scraped**), I print the content of listeLiens, I have:

```
[nan, 'lien']
```

I don't understand why this 'nan' and why it displays also the name of the column "lien"

Comment: when I changed the following ```tableauLiens = pd.read_csv('dataset\\liensVilles.csv', encoding="utf-8", names= ['ville','lien'], dtype='unicode')``` with adding names=, now i have ony [nan] when I print the listeLiens

Comment: By the way I have to precise that I use multiprocessing for the scraping with: 
```if __name__ == "__main__":
    with Pool(30) as p:
        p.map(parse, listeLiens)```